# Keep toggled table after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a php page that on load shows a table by default, and that table is:

```
echo "<table class='tftable' border='1' id='table_L'>";
```

There is another table:

```
echo "<table class='tftable' border='1' id='table_P' style='display:none'>";
```

which I toggle on the page by the following javascript function:
function toggleTables(table_id)

```
{
    if(table_id == "table_L") {
        document.getElementById('table_L').style.display = "table";
        document.getElementById('table_P').style.display = "none";
        }
    else if(table_id == "table_P") {
        document.getElementById('table_P').style.display = "table";
        document.getElementById('table_L').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

So depending on which link user clicks, it displays the appropriate table. But then I have a form that based on selected values feeds the table data upon Submit. And the problem is, if user selects the table_P, which by default is hidden, then selects some dropdown values and submits the form, the page refreshes and table_L is loaded back again. How can I keep the same table selected even after the page reload? Is there some values I need to store to remember upon form submit?

```
<form method="post" action="">
selections...

<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" title="Run It!" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden field in the form that knows which table is currently visible. On submit, use that form data form the client to echo the proper table.

So your form would look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="tableid" value="table_P">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And serverside, the post body would contain the name of the table, and you would print the correct table.

Comment: Could you please show how to add that field and where? To the form tag?

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Well, you hardcoded value="table_P" in your input, but that's the thing, I wouldn't know which table is currently visible. I would have to have a function on submit to get that value. Which I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: How are you selecting the table? Like with tabs, separate from the form?